# Import Data Through Data Loader after converting relationship from lookup to master-detail

Tags: force.com, salesforce-id, data-loader

I have 1 custom object with 10000 records, now i want to customize this object & I want to connect this object with 1 object with master detail relationship,
so I have to 1st create lookup with that object & feel lookup field on child object with associated parent & then convert to master right??

So how to import that lookup field (Associated parent values) values with data loader?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to have the field Master-Detail, the field must be populated for all records.

To import the associated parent values, you can either specify the 18 character record Id during an insert/update/upsert, or you can specify one of the parent's external Id fields during an upsert.